# Cannot convert value of type NSData to type Data in coercion

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

I've looked at the other articles here in SO and none of them seem to explain what is going on here. They just show other ways to achieve the same thing (I'm fairly new to Swift).

I've got this code:

```
let imageData = imageDataAry.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSData
let image: UIImage = UIImage(data:imageData as Data, scale:1.0)!
```

As you can see I'm try to create a UIImage and I need to convert NSData to Data in Swift 4.0 and I get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type NSData to type Data in coercion

Can anyone please explain why and the best way to fix it?

Comment: Do not use `NSData` in Swift. That will fix the issue.

Comment: Is `imageDataArt` an `NSArray`? Why? Use a Swift array with the proper type and no casting is needed.

Comment: Thanks maddy. Yes it is stored as Data in an NSMutableArray.I am trying this now imageDataAry.object(at:0) and am getting an error Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'Data'. Any ideas why?

Comment: See my 2nd comment above. Don't use `NSMutableArray`. Use a Swift array of `Data`. Then all issues go away.

Comment: Thanks. There is something fundamental I'm not understanding. I've done that but when I try to insert a value I get this message which doesn't make any sense to me:  var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!) self.imageDataArray.insert(imageData, at: 0) error: Cannot convert value of type 'Data?' to expected argument type 'Data?'

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Just cast your array object to `Data` instead of `NSData`.

```
let imageData = imageDataAry.object(at: indexPath.row) as! Data
let image: UIImage = UIImage(data:imageData as Data, scale:1.0)!
```

Comment: Why would you need to cast to `Data`? If it's not already `Data` then the cast will fail and the app will crash. If the cast would succeed then it is already `Data` and the cast is pointless.